# How to avoid printing on screen all reading format error messages if just one reading format is not correct?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

This is my simple( test ) code:

```
MODULE TEST_MODULE

USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING

IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER, PARAMETER :: IP = C_INT
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: LP = C_BOOL
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: CP = C_CHAR

INTEGER( IP ), PARAMETER :: UN = 15
INTEGER( IP )            :: DATA_00, DATA_01, DATA_02
CHARACTER(*),  PARAMETER :: FMTR = 'BASE\DATA_STORAGE.TXT'

CONTAINS

FUNCTION DATA_READING( ) RESULT( ERROR_TMP )

  LOGICAL( LP ) :: ERROR_TMP

  ERROR_TMP = .FALSE.

  OPEN( UNIT = UN, FILE = FMTR, ACTION = 'READ', STATUS = 'UNKNOWN', ERR = 100 )

      READ( UN, * , ERR = 101 ) DATA_00
      READ( UN, * , ERR = 102 ) DATA_01
      READ( UN, * , ERR = 103 ) DATA_02

  CLOSE( UNIT = UN, STATUS = 'KEEP')

  RETURN

  100 WRITE(*,*) "ERROR - NO SUCH A FILE OR FILE LOCATION !!!"
  ERROR_TMP = .TRUE.

  101 WRITE(*,*) "ERROR - FMT OF READING - DATA_TMP_00 - 101 !!!"
  ERROR_TMP = .TRUE.

  102 WRITE(*,*) "ERROR - FMT OF READING - DATA_TMP_01 - 102 !!!"
  ERROR_TMP = .TRUE.

  103 WRITE(*,*) "ERROR - FMT OF READING - DATA_TMP_02 - 103 !!!"
  ERROR_TMP = .TRUE.

  END FUNCTION DATA_READING

END MODULE TEST_MODULE


PROGRAM TEST_CODE

USE, NON_INTRINSIC :: TEST_MODULE

IMPLICIT NONE

LOGICAL( LP ) :: GLOBAL_ERR

GLOBAL_ERR = DATA_READING()

IF ( GLOBAL_ERR ) STOP ( "ERROR - DATA READING !!!" )

PRINT *, DATA_00
PRINT *, DATA_01
PRINT *, DATA_02

END PROGRAM TEST_CODE
```

The `DATA_STORAGE.TXT` file contains:

`1407
 1408
 1409`

When I run the program, it will load the data from the specified file in the correct way - there will not be a global error message because all the data in the file is an integer type.
For example, if the changed value of the first data in `1407.23`,which is real type, after the startup, the program will print on the screen all the error labels, including the one about the existence of a global error.

My question is:

How to print on the screen only the error label that belongs to the data whose entry format is not correct?

The code was tested in two IDE:

```
Code::Blocks 1712 GFortan 6.3.0

Visual Studio 2010 with Intel Parallel XE 2011
```

Comment: Please give an example in case it goes wrong, but probably you will need a `RETURN` after the printing of each mesage.

Comment: @albert Just change first data from .txt file to real and start the code.

Comment: You do indeed just need some flow control to skip over/return between the various error reports.  Or use `iostat=` to get a status code and use conditionals on that.  Depending on which you'd prefer there are questions here covering both of those topics.

Comment: @francescalus In case of using `iostat = ierr` i must declare different `ierr( ierr1, ierr2,...)` for every single read line?

Comment: Just re-use, with `read(..., iostat=ierr) ...; if (iostat/=0) ...; read(...,iostat=ierr) ...`.

Comment: @francescalus That solution is useful for me but is there trick for removing `if` conditions blocks somewhere out of `read` block( somewhere afther `close`) for better code reading?

Comment: Surely having "if something unexpected happens, do this" _right next_ to the point of doing the thing is more readable than "if something unexpected happens, go to some arbitrary place in the code"?  If you are happy with this latter (which is what you currently have), then you can put `return` between each "exception block"  to avoid flowing from one to the next.